# Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when I build the android app:

Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

I've looked at other posts, and their solutions didn't work for me. I tried editing build.gradle and changed buildToolsVersion.

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsofdave.karen"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-v21']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing']
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
    }

}
```

How do I tell gradle to use the Build Tools 23 if it's already installed?

Comment: 1. close android studio and then replace 25 with your desired version, like 23, then reopen the project
2. change gradle file from android studio and then synch the gradle files

Comment: Why would you want to change it to 23, when the error says you need 25? The numbers next to `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` need to start with the same digits in the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

I was successful. First, you have to download the latest version of SDK (25.0.0), save it to a folder. In android studio, select Tools -> android -> SDK manager -> Edit. Select the path to the latest downloaded SDK file. Then run Gradle again!

If it still does not work then you have to download a new Android studio. During the installation process, save the SDK in another folder. In android studio, select Tools -> android -> SDK manager -> Edit. Select the path to the latest downloaded SDK file. Then run Gradle again!